# Order by RAND( ) on a HUGE table causes it to crash in MySQL.  Why?

Tags: mysql, crash, innodb, myisam

Good day, friends.  I'm running Fedora 13 on a 32b machine.

I have a huge table of 1.5B ip addresses (which will be split up when I have the resources, don't worry ;)).  When I run this query:

```
SELECT ip FROM ips ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 500000;
```

Sometimes the table crashes (I get the error "MySQL Table is Marked as Crashed and Should be Repaired"), sometimes it doesn't.  My question is; what sorts of things cause MyISAM or InnoDB tables to crash?  Does memory have an affect?  Because my system monitor shows it only uses about 30%.

Here is my.cnf (the default, installing from meta-package):

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Also; I hear PostGreSQL is 'more robust' and doesn't crash like MySQL does in these situations.  Is this true or is it a wives tale?

Comment: Can you define "Crash" a bit more precisely? Is the query simply not returning or are you getting error messages or is the entire machine hanging up or...

Comment: I get the error "MySQL Table is Marked as Crashed and Should be Repaired" when I run the query in the interactive terminal.

Comment: Change the title. The accepted answer and the other answer is no way related to the title!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorting `1500M` of IP addresses is not the best idea.

If you want `500K` random IP addresses, use this approach:

- [**Selecting random rows**](http://explainextended.com/2009/03/01/selecting-random-rows/)

It won't be too efficient as well, though, since it needs two passes over the table.

You may put a rough estimate of the `COUNT(*)` instead of the subquery. This will speed the query up, at cost of a slight opportunity of missing some addresses or getting fewer results than needed.

Comment: That's a great tip!  I love it.

Comment: This is not the answer to the question above!!

Answer (score 1):

order by rand() will cause a temporary table with filesort, I suspect your table crash is due to a memory limitation.  You can try adjusting your conf file to allow mysql to utilize more memory for temporary tables and sort buffers.

Comment: This answer is useful, but my harddrive is 3TB (of which 2.5 are free) so I'm quite sure it isn't the problem in my case (again, RAM usage is at about 30%).